# What are the things to be taken care of while buying a crystal oscillator?

Tags: pic, oscillator, crystal

I need an external crystal oscillator for PWM output of 10kHz using dsPIC30F2010

Comment: Read the datasheet of the dsPIC30F2010 to see the requirements. They are clearly listed.

Comment: This requirement is silly.  The PWM hardware in the dsPIC can divide down the clock to make the 10 kHz frequency you want.  A separate 10 kHz oscillator couldn't even be used for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you can either buy a crystal and place your own components around it, as usually described in various MCU data sheets, or you can buy a self contained oscillator module. If you are new to electronics the latter course is preferable because crystals can be quite sensitive to PCB or prototyping layout.

Answer (score 0):

If it's for an application, where stability and phase noise is not the limiting factor, then it's rather simple. For a single crystal (ie if you are using the microcontrollers oscillator) you only need to care about the initial frequency accuracy and the load capacitance. If you are buying a full oscillator, it is just the frequency accuracy. If stability is an issue too, then you need to care about temperature coefficient as well.